# Difference between versions of Report Viewer Control

Tags: report, reporting-services

There are several versions of the Report Viewer Redistributable.  If I'm reading things right, the versions do NOT correspond to a version of Reporting Services.  Is this correct?  They instead correspond to a version of the .net framework?

Is anyone holding a link to a comparison of versions (8, 9, and 10)?  I've tried searching for the information, but just can't find the answer to this one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, they do not correspond.

The schemas, you find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd297486%28v=sql.100%29)

- Report Viewer 2010 is version 3 and
  uses the RDL specification 2008. Its the version used in VS2010
- Report Viewer 2008 is version 2 and
  uses the RDL specification 2005. Its the version used in VS2008

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brianhartman/wheres-the-new-report-viewer) post from Brian Hartman leads you in the right direction concerning the new features but also if you want to know more about report viewer.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355701/rdl-client-side-local-reporting-on-net-4-0/3355862#3355862) post may interest you if you want to work with the 2010-version: