# ReportViewer 2010 struggling with polymorphism

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have a rdlc report that takes as a ReportDataSource a `List<BaseClass>`.
`BaseClass` has two derived classes `A` and `B`.
In the report, I group based on a property of the base class. As long as the list only contains objects of `A` or `B`, all works fine.   However if I mix instances from `A` and `B`, then the report creation fails with the following message:

*The Group expression used in grouping '[Group Name]' references a dataset field which contains an Error: FieldValueException*

The property returns for both classes a simple string literal, backed by a constant of the classes, there is nothing that could be wrong with this. I also checked all other used properties, but there is nothing wrong with them.
Has anybody else seen this behaviour or has someone an explantion for this behaviour? It seems to me that report viewer don't likes polymorphism! Could that be?

**Example**

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
   public abstract string GroupKey{get;}
}
public class A : BaseClass{
    public override string GroupKey{
       get{
          return ...
       }
    }
}
public class B : BaseClass{
    public override string GroupKey{
       get{
          return ...
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that this is another [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355701/rdl-client-side-local-reporting-on-net-4-0/3355862#3355862) of Report Viewer. As a solution I have created a class `C` that derives also from `BaseClass` and wrapps an instance of `BaseClass`.
Before providing my `List<BaseClass>` as a DataSource for Report Viewer, I wrap all contained instances of A and B with an instance of C and give then the list of C to Report Viewer. So all instances are of the same type and Report Viewer is happy.

**Here an example. I hope this helps someone in the same situation:**

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
   public string GroupKey{get;}
   public virtual C GetWorkaroundWrapper(){
       return new C(this);
   }
}
public class A : BaseClass{
    public override string GroupKey{
       get{
          return ...
          }
    }
}
public class B : BaseClass{
    public override string GroupKey{
       get{
          return ...
          }
    }
}
public class C : BaseClass{
    BaseClass m_baseClass;
    public C(BaseClass baseClass){
         if(null == baseClass){
             throw new ArgumentNullException("baseClass");
         }
         m_baseClass=baseClass;
    }
    public override string GroupKey{
         get{
             return m_baseCLass.GroupKey;
         }
    }
    public override C GetWorkaroundWrapper(){
         return this;
    }
}
```

The `GetWorkaroundWrapper`-Methodis only for convenience. With this, the creation of the wrapper is simplified:

```
List<C> workaroundList=new List<C>();
foreach(BaseClass item in sourceList){
 workaroundList.Add(item.GetWorkaroundWrapper());
}

dataSource.Value=workaroundList;
```

Please note that it is not important that the list is of `C`. It works also with a list of `BaseClass`, but its more clean to use a list of `C`.